# How to customize a reference?

Tags: bibliographies, cite-package

I need to customize a reference. Please see the following text. Thank you very much for any suggestion.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}

I cited the reference here \cite{ref1}, which gives the reference sequence 
as [1], [2], [3],..., with a title ``References''.
How to customize a reference that when cited it will assign the reference 
sequence as [A1], [A2], [A3],... with a title ``References A''. Also, the references are listed at the end of the article as [A1], [A2], [A3],...

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{ref1} name. 2001 Title of the reference.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you need to create several references _sections_ prefixed for example as *References A* (`[A1]`, `[A2]`, etc), *References B* (`[B1]`, `[B2]`, etc), etc?

Comment: @skpblack I have two separate files A and B actually. For file A, I need References A ([A1], [A2], etc); for file B, References B ([B1], [B2], etc). Thank you! Your idea is interesting as well. I will adopt this style next time if you could provide an approach to creating several references sections.